# Simple contour integration question?

Tags: integration, contour-integration

If you are trying to evaluate a real integral using contour integration, are you meant to find the poles first and then draw the contour around these poles?

So for example with this integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \, \frac{1}{z^2+1} dz$$

I know that there are poles at $ z = i, -i $. But for some reason they (a youtube video i was watching) drew a semi circle on the upper half plan before working out the poles and then said "we can see that we only need to worry about $ z = i$ ." i.e. they completely left $ z = -i$ out.

Is there a reason for this? Or did they get it wrong?

Comment: They looked at an upper semi circle which only enclosed the pole at $z = i$ so you only need to worry about this one. Have you learnt about Residues?

Comment: You are only interested in the part along the real axis, so if you take a semi circle in the upper half plane, and let the radius tends to infinity, you only have to worry about the pole $z=i$. (you could do the same for a semi circle in the lower half plane, but then you have to worry about the pole $z=-i$)

Comment: Thanks guys! I learnt about residues last year so im a little rusty